# jQuery don't include form field in validation

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a form on my site, when I click submit, I have a validation script that checks for empty fields. There is only one field in my form that is not required so I am trying to add that as an exception. Here is my current script

```
$("#quote_form").submit(function(){
    var isFormValid = true;

    $("input, select").not('.discount').each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0){
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
            isFormValid = false;
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });

    if (!isFormValid) {
        $('.error').text('**Please fill in all highlighted fields**');
    }
    else {
        $('.error').text('');
    }

    return isFormValid;
});
```

This works in that when I click submit it doesn't add the class "highlight" to the field that has the class "discount" HOWEVER, when I fill out all form fields except the discount one, it still won't send. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: There's no `.not()` in jquery maybe youre pertaining to the selector `:not`?

Comment: I thought there was a .not selector, see here http://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: @SamSkirrow sounds like you have an `input` with an empty value, perhaps a submit button/hidden input or something like that. Could you paste your markup?

Comment: you're correct @SamSkirrow

Comment: But @SamSkirrow i am pretty confused , you said `I click submit it doesn't add the class "highlight" to the field that has the class "discount"` but you use `.not('.discount')`

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't add that class as this is the input that isn't required. The issue is, when I don't fill out this input, it doesn't send - but it should because this field is never required

Comment: @SamSkirrow does it send if you do populate it (along with all of the other inputs)?

Comment: yes. I've got a workaround though, I've added the class '.required' to all the fields I need, and changed the line  $("input, select").not('.discount').each(function() to  $("input.required, select.required").each(function()

Comment: I still don't understand why it wouldn't work. [Looks fine in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gv62/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a more complete and simpler approach: use [jquery.validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

With this widely used plugin you can manage validation rules either by code or (suggested!) by css classes and attributes directly applied to your inputs (i.e. required, email, min/max length, min/max value, etc).

Check [here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) for few usage examples.

Note that error messages and corresponding localizations are already included.